# Getting an error with a 2D array in java

Tags: java

So im honestly stuck here, the a2[row][column] is in error but im not sure why. am i just missing something is close sight???

```
public class ArrayHW {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int [][] a2 = {{10,20,30,40},
            {50, 60, 70 , 80},
            {90, 100, 110, 120}};
    display2DArray();
}

public static void display2DArray() {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++){
            System.out.println(a2[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? Please don't leave us guessing -- post the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a scope issue in that the a2 2D int array has been declared inside of the main method and is thus visible only within the same main method. The display2DArray method cannot see nor operate on this variable. One decent solution is to give the display2DArray method an `int[][]` parameter and pass the array into the method. Note that the parameter name can be any valid variable name, but you'll need to use the same variable name within the display2DArray method.

```
public static void display2DArray(int[][] foo) {
    // avoid use of "magic" numbers and instead use the array's length field
    for (int row = 0; row < foo.length; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < foo[row].length; column++){
            System.out.println(foo[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call the method:

```
display2DArray(a2);
```

Another viable solution is to make a2 a static field of the class by declaring it in the class, not  in the main method.

Comment: ahhh okay! understood now. Is there a way of doing the same thing but without giving it that parameter?? like if i left it the way i had it, am i able to change like static void at all to something?

Comment: @ThePyroMark: yes, I already told you at the end of my answer how to do this without use of a parameter.